# Zoom option in Highchart not working for large amount of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I need to create a highchart with jquery. I have given the Zoom type as x. The Zoom option in chart is not working when there are large amount of data.
In my X-Axis I will be having date value :

Below is my chart implementation:

```
 // Global chart options
Highcharts.setOptions({
            chart: {
                borderRadius: 0,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#DADCE0',
                marginRight: 45,
                zoomType: 'x',
                width: 600,
                height: 400

            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                minRange: 8 * 24 * 3600000,
                labels: {
                    format: '{value:%m-%d-%Y}', //'{value:%m-%d-%Y}'
                    rotation: 45
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series:{
                    fillOpacity:0.1
                },
                spline: {
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false,
                        symbol: 'circle',
                        radius: 2,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    threshold: null
                },
                area: {
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false,
                        symbol: 'circle',
                        radius: 2,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    threshold: null
                }
            },
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });
         var chartJobCount = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container-segementReport',
                type: 'areaspline'
            },
            colors: ['#0D4F8B','#00CCFF', '#ff0000', '#ff69b4','#663399','#ffa500','#006400','#654321'],
            title: {
                text: 'Segments (Classic)'
            },
          yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Production Ratio'
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0, '', ',');
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.name + ' </b> <br/> Date : <b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%m-%d-%Y', this.x) + ' </b> <br/>  Production Ratio: <b>' + this.y + '</b>';
                }

            },

            series: getProductionRatio() --// This function will get the data for series
        });
```

When I try to zoom the chart, the contents present in the chart gets hided.

Is there anything that needs to taken care in the point interval for `X-Axis` ?

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Fiddle my dear Friend

Comment: You need to set a [zoomType](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.zoomType) flag and [minRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.minRange) on xAxis/yAxis. If problem still exists, pleace replicate that as jsfiddle.net